# Problem with custom resolution with AMD

Tags: display-resolution, amd-graphics, monitor, amdgpu, 23.10

I can't get the whole screen to work so if anyone here could help me it would be great... All I need is a way for 1920x1080_73.00 to work on my monitor as a DP-1/VGA-0. Does anyone else here knows how to fix the resolution here? because I can't really work on video editing at all... i'd like anyone here that could help me with this stuff because i really like video editing and gaming at all...

All i tried is using ||

```
$ sudo xrandr 
cvt 1920 1080 73.00
```

Without the * into it. It worked well to this point but when I add in:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_73.00" "1920x1080_73.00"  213.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1080 1083 1088 1129 -hsync +vsync
```

All it gives me back is:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default error message.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you include your Ubuntu version. First check if your AMD drivers are installed using [this](https://linuxconfig.org/amd-radeon-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation) guide. If not, you can use the same guide to install them. I once experienced this problem too.

Comment: But my Ubuntu version is actually 23.10.1... Is it possible to install this version of Ubuntu AMD Drivers for the version you suggested me to?

Comment: [Here](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-installing.html) is another tutorial on how to install them. Note that there is no specific Ubuntu version required to download. Since this comes from AMD itself, it may be more reliable than the one on my answer.